# vector while loop returning ONLY circuit breakers?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, circuit-breaker

practicing making vectors that can store data (eventually sum to find averages, etc).

I have done several "*vectors...*",  "*while loops*" & "*for (int i=0....)*" loops to enter variables into and express said vectors. when I tried this time, every time the "for loop" shows the circuit breaker "*while data1 != -1)....*"

To reiterate, the output has been "-1" for every variable I enter, which did NOT happen with earlier code, seen at the very bottom. The first codeblock isthe PROBLEM code:
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
 void stats() {
        double data1; //float average;
        std::vector<double> set1;
        std::cout << "enter value for data1" << endl; std::cin >> data1; set1.push_back(data1);
    
    while (data1 != -1) {
        std::cout << " enter values for data " << endl; std::cin >> data1;
        set1.push_back(data1); //double sum1 = data1 + data1;   
        
    }if (data1 = -1) { set1.pop_back(); }
            std::cout << "finished putting in data " << endl;
            
            for (size_t m = 0; m < set1.size(); m++) {
                std::cout << data1 << ", "; }
            std::cout << "end of lists; " << endl; //std::cout << sum1;

}
```

---

Code that worked before: shown to show I am doing essentially same things:

```
std::vector<int> set;
    int g; std::cout << "enter ge" << endl; std::cin >> g; while (g != -1) { std::cout << "enter another fucking variable for g;" << endl; std::cin >> g; set.push_back(g); };
    if (g = -1) { set.pop_back(); }
    for (size_t I = 0; I < set.size(); I++) {std::cout << set[I] << ", ";}
```

Comment: Comparison needs `==` , not `=`.

Comment: What does "I have done several '_vectors..._'" mean? Also, it seems like you are using "circuit breaker" to mean something other than its usual meaning. This makes your question rather unclear to me. Maybe you could be a bit less terse with how you phrase things? We don't charge by the word.

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop below, you are printing the value stored in data1 variable. And data1 variable contains -1. That's why you are getting -1 as output.

```
for (size_t m = 0; m < set1.size(); m++) {
        std::cout << data1 << ", "; }
```

you can either change the variable data1 to set1[m] like below

```
for (size_t m = 0; m < set1.size(); m++) {
        std::cout << set1[m] << ", "; }
```

or you can use for each  like below

```
for(double num : set1)
        cout<<num<<" ";
```

Comment: found it. gracias